# Conditional within a render in the content display component in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that needs to display the details of a movie according to the id that is passed in the URL (parameter). I'm having difficulty doing the conditional on the RENDER method. It's probably quite simple, but I'm still not very familiar with the React flow. Can you give me an idea?

Ex: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zxwpr07jvp)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import api from "../../services/api";

export default class Movie extends Component {
  state = {
    movies: [],
    movieId: {}
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;

    const response = await api.get("");
    const currentParams = this.props.match.params;

    this.setState({
      movies: response.data,
      movieId: `${id}`
    });
    console.log(this.state.movies);
    console.log(this.state.movieId);
  }

  render() {
    const movies = this.state.movies,
      currentParams = this.state.movieId;

    return (
      <div className="movie-info">
        {this.state.movies.map(movie => (
          if( movie.event.id === currentParams ) {
            <h1 key={movie.event.id}>{movie.event.title}</h1>
          }
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use `Array.find` instead of `Array.map + filter`

Comment: In the typical React workflow, conditional rendering is done through ternary operators: `render() { return (this.state.condition ? <div>true</div> : <div>false</div>); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not want to use `map` in this case since you only want to render one movie. You could instead use the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method and render that single movie if it's found.

```
class Movie extends Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    const { movies, movieId } = this.state;
    const movie = movies.find(movie => movie.event.id === movieId);

    return (
      <div className="movie-info">
        {movie ? <h1 key={movie.event.id}>{movie.event.title}</h1> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```